# What to Call a Document if It Has a Deadline?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

There is a document that needs to be signed before a set date, and it will expire/become unusable if it's not signed before the set date. What to call this document?

I want to say "dated document", or "timed document", but they don't sound quite right to me. Is there a better way to describe a "document with a deadline"? Or is any of these two correct?

Thanks in advance.

Note: The document is an electronic document, and it's being electronically signed, which is how the time of signing is being tracked.

Comment: I'd suggest [time-sensitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/time-sensitive).

Comment: @KateBunting thanks for your comment. I probably should have mentioned that the context is a business application. Also, please see the note I added to the question. I don't believe "time-sensitive document" is the right term for my purpose.

Comment: @KateBunting actually, on a second thought, maybe that's the word I'm looking for